$12$ white and $14$ black balls are distributed among $8$ identical urns so that there is atleast one ball in each urn.

$12$ white and $14$ black balls are distributed among $8$ identical urns so that there is atleast one ball in each urn. Balls are all alike except for the colour and each box can hold any number of balls. The number of different distributions of the balls is:

Note: I've solved similar question 6 white and 6 black balls in 10 urns, without empty urns and found answer to be $10$ by making cases. But in this problem it is difficult to make cases. Can you please help me solve this problem?

I wasn't going to respond, because my approach is fairly pathetic.  However, since no one else responded, I will go ahead.
First of all, you have to identify each way of positive-integer-partitioning the number $~12,~$  where each partition has no more than $~8~$ terms.  If you were to list these partitions in reverse-lexicographical order, the list would look like

Partition-1
$12 ~: ~1 ~$ term.

Partition-2
$11 + 1 ~: ~2 ~$ terms.

Partition-3
$10 + 2 ~: ~2 ~$ terms.

Partition-4
$10 + 1 + 1 ~: ~3 ~$ terms.

$\cdots$

Partition-a
$2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 ~: ~8 ~$ terms.


So, I am assuming that there are a total of $~a~$ distinct partitions, where the number of terms in each partition is between $~1~$ and $~8,~$ inclusive.
Similarly, assume that there are a total of $~b~$ distinct partitions of the number $~14,~$ where the number of terms in each partition is between $~1~$ and $~8,~$ inclusive.

Then, there are $~(a \times b)~$ mutually exclusive ways of pairing some partition of $~12~$ with some partition of $~14.$  Each of these pairings must be individually examined.
Assume that you are looking at Partition-r of $~12,~$ coupled with Partition-s of $~14.~$
Further assume that Partition $~r~$ has $~x~$ terms, and Partition-s has $~y~$ terms.
If $~x + y < 8,~$ then the pairing of Partition-r with Partition-s can be ignored.
If $~x + y = 8,~$ then, since the urns are considered indistinguishable, there is only 1 way of distributing the balls that conform to [White:Partition-r] + [Black:Partition-s].
The enumeration complexity grows very fast, when $~x + y > 8.~$  The best that I can do is examine a couple of illustrative examples.

$\underline{\text{Example 1}}$
Assume that Partition-r represents $~6 + 3  + 2 + 1,~$ which has $~4~$ terms.
Assume that Partition-s represents $~4 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1,~$ which has $~5~$ terms.
Then, exactly one of the urns must receive both white balls and black balls.  There are $~4~$ distinct choices for which Partition-r term will be overlapped, and $~4~$ distinct choices for which Partition-s term will be overlapped.  Therefore, this particular [White:Partition-r] + [Black:Partition-s] pairing represents $~(4 \times 4)~$ distinct distributions.

$\underline{\text{Example 2}}$
Assume that Partition-r represents $~4 + 3 + 2  + 2 + 1,~$ which has $~5~$ terms.
Assume that Partition-s represents $~4 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1,~$ which has $~5~$ terms.
There must be $~[ ~(5 + 5) - 8 ~] = 2~$ urns that contain both white and black balls.
If you assume that the two overlapped Partition-r terms will not both be $~2,~$ and you also assume that the two overlapped Partition-s terms will not both be $~4,~$ then the number of distinct distributions is $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} = 36.$
Now there are $~3~$ other mutually exclusive cases to consider:

You could have both of the overlapped Partition-r terms equal $~2,~$ while the two overlapped Partition-s terms are not both $~4.$  In that event, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}~$ ways of selecting the two Partition-s terms to be overlapped.

You could have both of the overlapped Partition-s terms equal $~4,~$ while the two overlapped Partition-r terms are not both $~2.$  In that event, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}~$ ways of selecting the two Partition-r terms to be overlapped.

You could have both of the overlapped Partition-s terms equal $~4,~$ and both of the overlapped Partition-r terms equal $~2.$  In that event, there is $~1~$ way of performing the overlaps.


Therefore, this particular [White:Partition-r] + [Black:Partition-s] pairing represents $~[ ~(6 \times 6) + 6 + 6 + 1 ~]$ distinct distributions.

With generating and functions and the symbolic method we have the following.
The species in question is a multiset of pairs of non-negative integers where not both zero. Let's use variable $z$ to record the size of the multiset and variables $x,y$ to record the number of white and black balls. The generating function is (calculations are similar to those in wikipedia but since we have these multiple variables with different weights I'll add them here)
$$ \begin{aligned}
G(x,y,z) &= \prod_{(a,b)\in \mathbb N^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}} (1-x^ay^bz)^{-1} \\
&= \exp \left(\sum_{(a,b)\in \mathbb N^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}} -\log(1-x^ay^bz) \right) \\
&=  \exp \left(\sum_{(a,b)\in \mathbb N^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j} x^{aj}y^{bj}z^j \right) \\
&= \exp \left(  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^j}{j} \left( \frac{1}{(1-x^j)(1-y^j)} - 1 \right) \right)
\end{aligned}$$
Since we only need the coefficient of $z^8$, we can cut the sum at $j=8$. And similarly when expanding the exponential. In fact, we only ever need to keep the powers of $z$ up to $8$. Similarly for $x$ and $y$ (up to $12$ and $14$). Still, it's an intensive calculation but a computer will do it. Sage code:
def gf(a, b, k):
    R0.<x,y> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=a+b+1)
    R.<z> = PowerSeriesRing(R0, default_prec=k+1)
    g = exp(sum(z^j/j*(1/((1-x^j)*(1-y^j))-1) for j in range(1, k+1)))
    show(g[k][a+b])

gf(12, 14, 8)

For the life of me, I don't know how to easily extract a particular coefficient from multivariate power series so I just show the whole thing where powers of $x$ and $y$ sum to $26$:
$$
288 x^{26} + 1177 x^{25} y + 3410 x^{24} y^{2} + 7745 x^{23} y^{3} + 15190 x^{22} y^{4} + 26295 x^{21} y^{5} + 41426 x^{20} y^{6} + 59955x^{19} y^{7} + 80900x^{18} y^{8} + 102353 x^{17} y^{9} + 122354 x^{16} y^{10} + 138527 x^{15} y^{11} + \color{green} {149170 x^{14} y^{12}} + 152809 x^{13} y^{13} + 149170 x^{12} y^{14} + 138527 x^{11} y^{15} + 122354 x^{10} y^{16} + 102353 x^{9} y^{17} + 80900 x^{8} y^{18} + 59955 x^{7} y^{19} + 41426 x^{6} y^{20} + 26295 x^{5} y^{21} + 15190 x^{4} y^{22} + 7745 x^{3} y^{23} + 3410 x^{2} y^{24} + 1177 x y^{25} + 288 y^{26}
$$
